# Can't change keyboard settings on Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, xorg, keyboard

I want to swap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys on my keyboard. I go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout Settings -> Options` and check `Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock` under `Ctrl Key Position`. I check that my keyboard (
English US) has the new key bindings.

However, when I exit settings, the keybindings switch back to default. How can I make my custom settings stay? I don't see a "Save" button anywhere.

Comment: There is no `Save` button in Gnome.  After you change the setting, it should become effective immediately.

Comment: @Mikel I know, that's why I'm confused as to how I can make the changes permanent.

Comment: WFW on Fedora 16.  What version of Fedora are you using?

Comment: What does WFW mean? I'm using Fedora 16, as noted in the title. I don't know what other version you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to write `WFM` meaning Works For Me.  So I don't understand why it's not working for you.  Need more details.  Are you using multiple locales?  Is there anything non-standard about your setup?

Comment: Good catch! I had IBUS on for Chinese input. Quit out of that, made my changes, and the changes stuck. Now I just need to figure out how to make IBUS behave. If you write up an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the x keymap directly using the command line is by far my preferred way of dealing with keymaps, and it's very disto-agnostic, so any solution you come up with will stand you in good stead.

Try this:

```
setxkbmap -print | xkbcomp -xkb -o original.xkb -
```

this will make a backup of your original keymap. Then do

```
cp original.xkb switch-CAPS-LCTL.xkb
```

Now edit switch-CAPS-LCTL and find the lines that read

```
<CAPS> = ??;
<LCTL> = ??;
```

where ?? is a number. On mine, these are two digit numbers, 66 and 37 respectively. Just switch them around and you're done.

```
xkbcomp switch-CAPS-LCTL.xkb $DISPLAY
```

switches the layout, and

```
xkbcomp original.xkb $DISPLAY
```

will restore the old configuration.

If you are going to be using these two keymaps concurrently, for maximum user-friendliness, just make two aliases to handle these keymap changes, and plop the keymaps into a hidden directory like `~/.stuff`

```
mkdir ~/.stuff
mv original.xkb switch-CAPS-LCTL.xkb ~/.stuff
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following to ~/.bashrc:

```
alias capswitch="xkbcomp ~/.stuff/switch-CAPS-LCTL.xkb $DISPLAY"
alias ctrlswitch="xkbcomp ~/.stuff/original.xkb $DISPLAY"
```

then,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

if you want the changes to take effect immediately, typing `capswitch` and `ctrlswitch` to change the keymap.